# Running discord bot using quart python

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, discord.py, quart

I am trying to create a discord bot with two features.

1. To update everyone in the server about some info (this is done by using webhook and a uptimerobot to call the webhook)
2. Community in the server can prompt the bot to provide additional info by telling the bot the ID of.

I am using app.route for the first feature and on_message() as the second one. But only the first one is working.

This is the snippet of my code

```html
import discord
import asyncio
import os
from quart import Quart
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import requests
import datetime
from datetime import timezone
import json
import random
import nest_asyncio

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
OS_TOKEN = os.getenv('OPENSEA_TOKEN')

nest_asyncio.apply()

app = Quart(__name__)
client = discord.Client()

@app.before_serving
async def before_serving():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    await client.login(TOKEN)
    loop.create_task(client.connect())

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    
    print('in func')


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Initiated!")


@app.route("/send")
async def broadcast():
    for server in client.guilds:
        for channel in server.text_channels:
            try:
                await channel.send("test")
            except Exception:
                continue
            else:
                break

    return "hello world"

app.run()
```

I managed to run both separately. But when I run them together, only the webhook is working and any @client modules are not working. Also I migrated from flask to quart because I read somewhere that flask can not run both itself and discord server.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think u might have forgotten to check the needed permissions in the discord dev portal. and also I solved my somehow similar problem by replacing @client.event(s) with @bot.event

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).